# how to find creation time of NiFi processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

I wanted to know who created and creation time of processor and RPG. i checked in processors and RPG, but could not find this information.
any way to find creation time of NiFi processor and RPG

Answer (score 1):

@Natrajan,

You can retrieve these info only if you have LDAP or AD integrated with Nifi. You can click on 'Flow configuration history' present in the top right sandwich icon and get all the details.

[image]

Comment: The Flow configuration history has all the processor details but it records the modified date and time only, not created time